# Sed, insert a line after a pattern match and ignore any commented line strating with #

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I would like to insert a line after a pattern match and ignore any commented line ( starting with '#' ) in Bash shell using `sed`.

Here is an example: inserting a new line after `pattern`:

**Input file:**

```
foo
Art 
street 
#pattern
foo
pattern
color
```

**Output:**

```
foo
Art 
street 
#pattern
foo
pattern
NEW LINE HERE
color
```

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`:

```
$ cat file
foo
Art
street
#pattern
foo
pattern
color

$ sed '/^[^#]*pattern/ a NEW LINE HERE' file
foo
Art
street
#pattern
foo
pattern
NEW LINE HERE
color
```

Comment: You can also use `n` to skip the `#` lines:  `'/^#/n;/pattern/a ...`  This is helpful if you have a number of regexes that all need to skip comment lines.  Skip the comments with `n`, and then the rest of the regexes don't have to worry about comments.

Comment: That would be a clever improvement. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

Another approach with sed:

```
sed 's/^pattern.*/&\nNEW LINE HERE/' file
```

Replace line starting with `pattern` with matching line(`&`) followed by new line(`\n`) and desired string.

Comment: Very simple and straightforward ++. The only downside, I think, is that this will only work if the pattern is at the beginning of the line. Is that right?

Comment: You're right. The anchor could be replaced with your pattern `^[^#]*`.

Answer (score 0):

try following too once.

```
awk '/pattern/ && !/#/{print $0 ORS "NEW LINE HERE";next} 1'   Input_file
```